# How to create directory nested JSON object to store value?

Tags: javascript, json

How to create directory like structure in JSON that on insertion value is stored inside last JSON object?

example of output :

```
 let obj = {
     value : 5,
     next : {
       value : 10,
       next : {
          value : 15,
          next : {
             value : 20,
             next : null
                 }
              }
            }
          }
```

Now, if we have to insert 25 then it must be stored in the last next node which is after value 20.

Comment: Do you want to make the insert position compared by the value? So if insert 13,it will between 10 and 15?

Comment: no, value must be inserted at the last position always in JSON.

Comment: Check my post answer

Comment: That doesn't look anything like a directory structure, more like a linked list. Why not just store a normal array instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It finds the next pointer which has null, so **it understands the last node wherever the next pointer is null.**

```js
let obj = {
  value: 5,
  next: {
    value: 10,
    next: {
      value: 15,
      next: {
        value: 20,
        next: null,
      },
    },
  },
};

function add(newNode) {
  let temp = obj;
  while (temp.next != null) temp = temp.next;
  temp.next = newNode;
  return temp;
}

add({ value: 101, next: null });

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

If `obj` has only one value in each level,then below is a reference for you

```js
let obj = {
     value : 5,
     next : {
       value : 10,
       next : {
          value : 15,
          next : {
             value : 20,
             next : null
                 }
              }
            }
          } 

const insert = (value,data) =>{
  let next = data.next
  let prev = null
  while(next!=null){
    prev = next
    next = next.next
  }
  prev.next = {'value':value,next:null}
  return data
}

console.log(insert(22,obj))
```